# How to create a static block to get other products from the current page PRODUCT MANUFACTURER

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, static-block, cms-block

I need to create a static block and place the block in view.phtml.

Static block should collect and display 5 random products from the Manufacturer.

Is it possible? if yes anybody give me the code?

Answer (score 0):

Create static block using below code:

```
 {{block type="core/template" name="random_manufacture_products" template="yourtemplatepath/random.phtml"}}
```

create template file name with **random.phtml** add below code:

```
<?php        
    $manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getManufacturer();

    $productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                         ->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$manufacturer);
    $productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
    $productCollection->limit(5);

    foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
       echo $product->getName();
    }
```

add below code in view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("cms/block")->setBlockId("your-static-block-id")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: I have to use merchant_name instead of Manufacturer. shall I use $manufacturer = $this->getProduct()->getmerchant_name();   ?

Comment: You can use getMerchantName()

Comment: Not working... do I need to edit anything here "->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer',$manufacturer);"  ?

Comment: Yes change it `->addAttributeToFilter('merchant_name',$manufacturer)`

Comment: It's just blank in frontend

Comment: updated answer check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37712/discussion-between-doodu-and-prashant-valanda).

Comment: It calls the product names only... how can I call the product image, price and i need the url?

Comment: check code of app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/list.phtml you will see code there to get all information about product

Comment: Can you plz check this page for more detailed description? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108947/how-to-call-grid-view-block-to-my-own-random-phtml

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Create static block **Cms->Static Blocks** set it's **identifier** = **relatedproduct**
and put below code and save it.

```
{{block type="core/template" name="relatedproduct" template="template_folder/relatedproduct.phtml"}}
```

Step 2: In `relatedproduct.phtml` paste below code and save it.

```
<?php  
$currentProduct = Mage::registry('current_product');
$currentManufacturer = $currentProduct->getManufacturer();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$products->addAttributeToFilter('status', array("eq" => 1));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('manufacturer', array("eq" => $currentManufacturer));
$products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', array("eq" => 4));
$products->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$products->getSelect()->limit(5);
foreach ($products as $product)  {
 echo $product->getName();
}
?>
```

Step 3: Now call your static block in your catalog/product/view.phtml using this code:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("cms/block")->setBlockId("relatedproduct")->toHtml();?>
```

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$products' (T_VARIABLE) in /relatedproduct.phtml on line 6

Comment: Updated the answer there was missing (;) in line

Comment: It's not calling the products... Just remaining blank..

Comment: Please in template relatedproduct.phtml  add echo before $currentManufacturer and see your attribute value is showing or not also please share template code here for check

Comment: Can you plz check this page for more detailed description? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/108947/how-to-call-grid-view-block-to-my-own-random-phtml