# How to copy "list view" style to a new file random.phtml?

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, frontend, static-block, phtml

I have created a random.phtml with the following code to list few products in the product page.

```
<?php        
$manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getMerchantName();

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('merchant_name',$manufacturer);
$productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);

foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
   echo $_product->getName();
}
?>
```

then created Static Block "random_product_brand" with

```
Other Items from this manufacturer
{{block type="core/template" name="random_manufacture_products" template="random/random.phtml"}}
```

then added the following block to view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock("cms/block")->setBlockId('random_product_brand')->toHtml();?>
```

But it just shows the plain product name in frond end.

[image]

Now I need to show the product as in product list page. (Image, Name, price etc...) like this

[image]

Here is my list.phtml code:

```
<div class="products-list-grid columns<?php echo $_columnCount ?>">
<?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): $i++; ?>
<div class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
<?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
<?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php include('view/labels.phtml')  ?>
<?php $mainImg = $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize); ?>
<?php if($hoverSwap): $backImg = $this->getLayout()->createBlock("ajax/listmedia")->setTemplate("catalog/product/list/media.phtml")->setData('size', $imgSize)->setData('product', $_product)->toHtml(); endif; ?>

<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
<?php if($backImg != 'null' && $backImg): ?><img src="<?php echo $backImg ?>" width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /><?php endif; ?>
<img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize($imgSize) ?>" <?php if($backImg != 'null' && $backImg): ?>onmouseover="hideImage(this)" onmouseout="showImage(this)"<?php endif; ?> width="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" height="<?php echo $imgSize ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
</a>

<div id="productimgover<?php echo $_product->getId()?>" style="display: none;"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(64); ?>" width="64" height="64" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" /></div>

<div class="moreinfo">
<h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
<div id='productname<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style='display:none'><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></div>


<?php   
$merchant_name = $_product->getAttributeText('merchant_name');
if ($merchant_name){?>
<div>by <?php echo $merchant_name;?> </div>
<?php }

else if ($_product->getIsEbayaffiliate()) { ?>
<div>by eBay</div>
<?php }

else { ?>
<div>by Home Done</div>
<?php } ?>


<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<?php if ( !($_product->getTypeInstance(true)->hasRequiredOptions($_product) || $_product->isGrouped()) ) { ?>
<p>
<?php if ($product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_product->getId())); { ?>
<?php if ($merchant_name){ ?>
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
<button type="button" title="View Product Detail" class="button btn-cart"><span><span>View Product Detail</span></span> </button>
</a>
<?php } else if ($product->getIsEbayaffiliate()) { ?>
<a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>">
<button type="button" title="View Product Detail" class="button btn-cart"><span><span>View Product Detail</span></span> </button>
</a>
<?php } else {  ?>

<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="<?php if($enableAjax): ?>setLocationAjax<?php else: ?>setLocation<?php endif; ?>('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
</p>

<?php } else { ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="<?php if($enableAjax): ?>showOptions('<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')<?php else: ?>setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>','<?php echo $_product->getId()?>')<?php endif;?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
<a href='<?php echo $this->getUrl('ajax/index/options',array('product_id'=>$_product->getId()));?>' class='fancybox' id='fancybox<?php echo $_product->getId()?>' style="display: none;" ><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
<?php }  ?>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
<?php if(themeOptions('addto')): ?>
<ul class="add-to-links">
<?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
<li>+ <a href="<?php echo $this->helper('wishlist')->getAddUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
<li>+ <span class="separator">|</span> <a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare') ?></a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>
</div>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

any help Would be appreciated.

Comment: NEVER order by RAND() for MySQL. It isn't cached. Alternatives: https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/

Answer (score 0):

For this case,you need to create a custom block class by

- ***`Creating new extension and create a new block for your collection`***
- or Create Block class file `Random.php` at `app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/`

Then at new block class write your code.

For my point of view,First copy code from  *app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/New.php*

and then that class(`Mage_Catalog_Block_Random`) on _`getProductCollection` function change your collection code.

**Random.php may be:**

```
<?php
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Random extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Default value for products count that will be shown
     */
    const DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT = 10;

    /**
     * Products count
     *
     * @var null
     */
    protected $_productsCount;

    /**
     * Initialize block's cache
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();

        $this->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('empty', 6)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('one_column', 5)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('two_columns_left', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('two_columns_right', 4)
            ->addColumnCountLayoutDepend('three_columns', 3);

        $this->addData(array('cache_lifetime' => 86400));
        $this->addCacheTag(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::CACHE_TAG);
    }

    /**
     * Get Key pieces for caching block content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCacheKeyInfo()
    {
        return array(
           'CATALOG_PRODUCT_NEW',
           Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(),
           Mage::getDesign()->getPackageName(),
           Mage::getDesign()->getTheme('template'),
           Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerGroupId(),
           'template' => $this->getTemplate(),
           $this->getProductsCount()
        );
    }

    /**
     * Prepare and return product collection
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection|Object|Varien_Data_Collection
     */
    protected function _getProductCollection()
    {
        if(Mage::registry('current_product')){
        $manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getMerchantName();


        /** @var $collection Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection */
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
        $collection->setVisibility(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->getVisibleInCatalogIds());


        $collection = $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($collection)
            ->addStoreFilter()
            ->addAttributeToFilter('merchant_name',$manufacturer)

        $collection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
        $collection->getSelect()->limit(5);  
        ;
        }else{
        return false;
        }


        return $collection;
    }

    /**
     * Prepare collection with new products
     *
     * @return Mage_Core_Block_Abstract
     */
    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->setProductCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    /**
     * Set how much product should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @param $count
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_New
     */
    public function setProductsCount($count)
    {
        $this->_productsCount = $count;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get how much products should be displayed at once.
     *
     * @return int
     */
    public function getProductsCount()
    {
        if (null === $this->_productsCount) {
            $this->_productsCount = self::DEFAULT_PRODUCTS_COUNT;
        }
        return $this->_productsCount;
    }
}
```

### edit:

Change block type from core/template to catalog/randon

so

```
{{block type="core/template" name="random_manufacture_products" template="random/random.phtml"}}
```

**should be**

```
{{block type="catalog/random" name="random_manufacture_products" template="random/random.phtml"}}
```

Also,no need of  use

```
$manufacturer = Mage::registry('current_product')->getMerchantName();

$productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                     ->addAttributeToFilter('merchant_name',$manufacturer);
$productCollection->getSelect()->order('RAND()');
$productCollection->getSelect()->limit(5);

foreach ($productCollection as $_product) {
   echo $_product->getName();
}
```

***at random.phtml and  make $_productCollection=$this->getProductCollection() first of  this file file***

Comment: I have edited my query. Can you plz check this?